# Screen is black for 15 seconds at boot before browser starts. Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, boot, browser, raspberry-pi

I am using chromium in kiosk mode. Touch screen without mouse and keyboard.
The browser is started in /boot/xinitrc seen below.
At boot I can see on the screen the different processes being started, but at the end the screen goes black for about 15 seconds before the browser starts. What is wrong? The browser after boot works fine.

```
#!/bin/sh
while true; do

    # Clean up previously running apps, gracefully at first then harshly
    killall -TERM chromium 2>/dev/null;
    killall -TERM matchbox-window-manager 2>/dev/null;
    sleep 2;
    killall -9 chromium 2>/dev/null;
    killall -9 matchbox-window-manager 2>/dev/null;

    # Clean out existing profile information
    rm -rf /home/pi/.cache;
    rm -rf /home/pi/.config;
    rm -rf /home/pi/.pki;

    # Generate the bare minimum to keep Chromium happy!
    mkdir -p /home/pi/.config/chromium/Default
    sqlite3 /home/pi/.config/chromium/Default/Web\ Data "CREATE TABLE meta(key LONGVARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY, value LONGVARCHAR); INSERT INTO meta VALUES('version','46');$

    # Disable DPMS / Screen blanking
    xset -dpms
    xset s off

    # Reset the framebuffer's colour-depth
    fbset -depth $( cat /sys/module/*fb*/parameters/fbdepth );

    # Hide the cursor (move it to the bottom-right, comment out if you want mouse interaction)
    xwit -root -warp $( cat /sys/module/*fb*/parameters/fbwidth ) $( cat /sys/module/*fb*/parameters/fbheight )

    # Start the window manager (remove "-use_cursor no" if you actually want mouse interaction)
    matchbox-window-manager -use_titlebar no -use_cursor no &

    # Start the browser (See http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)
    chromium-browser  --app=http://localhost:8080/webvisu.htm

done;
```

Comment: Maybe it simply takes so long to load and initialize the window manager and the browser. I don't expect Pi to be super fast in this matter. In such case the answer to "what is wrong?" is "nothing". Just a guess. Have you tried anything to rule out or to confirm this possibility?

Comment: Not really because I don't know what I can do. I am not an expert in display manager. I don't even know which program is using /boot/xinitrc. Is it lightdm ?